# How to Resolve `permission denied` on Cloned Image

Tags: permissions, sudo, gpio

I had a Linux image on an Orange Pi that was had access to the GPIO pins via the command line `sudo echo 1 > /sys/class/gpio_sw/PA1/data`.

I took the SD card out and put it into another Orange Pi and now when I run the command I get a `permission denied` error on the new device.

Why aren't the permissions carrying over?

How can I set the permissions on the new device to prevent this error?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect, based on [some](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/60240/what-sets-ownership-and-privileges-on-dev-gpiomem) [various](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=121030) [research](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/60240/what-sets-ownership-and-privileges-on-dev-gpiomem) that the user on the 2nd Pi is not a member of the gpio group. Fix that with:

```
useradd -G www-data gpio
```

(substitute www-data for your actual user, of course)

By the way, running `sudo echo 1 > ...` ends up writing "1" (the `echo 1` is run as sudo, pointlessly) to the file as your non-sudo user, since the redirection is happening "outside" of the sudo command.

Comment: Your second point confuses me. Could you please provide an example that removes my redundancy?

Comment: On a system where you have enough 'sudo' permissions to do something like this, run (1) `sudo echo 1 > /tmp/file1`, and (2) `echo 1 | sudo tee /tmp/file2` and then compare the ownerships of file1 and file2. You created file1 as your non-sudo user and file2 as root.